# How to compile my Electron code for Windows on a Mac including native sqlite3 module?

Tags: electron, node-sqlite3, node-pre-gyp

My goal is to create a distribution for Mac AND an other for Windows. I want to create these two distributions from my Mac. For the moment, my distribution for Mac works well.

But I still have problem with sqlite3 module for the Windows distribution.

The only native module that my app uses is sqlite3.

I really don't know what to do to finally get my app works correctly on Windows. I don't want to compile my code on a Windows machine. I want to compile my code on my Mac only.

### My config is :

- node v12.2.0
- npm v6.9.0
- electron v5.0.1
- sqlite3 v4.0.8
- MacOS Mojave v10.14.0

### Trying to compile sqlite3 module for Windows with :

```
node-pre-gyp install --directory=./node_modules/sqlite3 --target_platform=win32 --target_arch=x64 --target=12.2.0
```

## node-pre-gyp returns these messages :

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
Warning: node-pre-gyp could not find exact match for 12.2.0
Warning: but node-pre-gyp successfully choose 12.0.0 as ABI compatible target
Warning: node-pre-gyp could not find exact match for 12.2.0
Warning: but node-pre-gyp successfully choose 12.0.0 as ABI compatible target

[sqlite3] Success: "/Users/Flooder/Programmes/electron/c4/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v72-win32-x64/node_sqlite3.node" is installed via remote
```

---

I get a **new directory** : ./node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v72-win32-x64

I **rename** this new directory for : ./node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/electron-v5.0-win32-x64

### When I try my new distribution on Windows machine, I get this error :

Uncaught Exception:
Error: The module D:\c4\resources\app\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\electron-v5.0-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node was compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE 72. This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 70. Please try re-compiling or re-installing the module (for instance, using 'npm rebuild' or 'npm install').

### ...

I'm stuck with this problem since many weeks...

**Is it really possible to compile sqlite3 module for Windows from a Mac?**

**Is node-pre-gyp the right solution for this? How?**

Comment: I've run into a similar issue with `node-canvas` – ("NODE_MODULE_VERSION " mismatch, etc.). Spent a few days juggling versions of everything but finally gave up.

Comment: I will give up soon too my friend!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, here is my solution :

- Installed Parallel Desktop on my mac;
- Installed Windows 10 in this virtual machine;
- Installed node, npm, python, electron, electron-rebuild, sqlite, etc. on the virtual Windows machine;
- Recompiled sqlite3 with "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3" on the virtual machine
- Copied the new ./node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/electron-v5.0-win32-x64 from Windows to Mac
- On the mac, recompiled my electron app for PC with electron-packager

And now, the new compiled version for Windows works on a Win machine!